# How to split text in 2 textviews like if there were 1?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listview where each item has 2 images, one on the right and the other on the left. Between them there is a textview that is filled from data. If text is long then it can continue down but there is a lot of free space just as you can see in the image. I want to use this space also to display text. I have been looking around the web and I have seen things like this http://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/downloads/detail?name=FlowTextDemo.zip&can=2&q= but this is useless. I don't want to lose the control of the images because I need their click method. What is the best way to do it? I have thought that maybe I can put a textview between images and an other down and when the first is filled continue in the second one but how can I know how many letters can keep the first textview?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why `FlowTextView` (that you linked to) won't work for you. It's derived from `RelativeLayout` and flows text around any child views. The child views can be your images, positioned as you normally would in a `RelativeLayout`. Their `onClick` methods should work just fine.

```
<com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/the_text >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onTopLeftClick"
        android:src="@drawable/top_left_image" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onTopRightClick"
        android:src="@drawable/top_right_image" />

</com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView>
```

You will need to set the text in code, or else extend `FlowTextView` and define your own custom attribute(s) to do it from xml.

Comment: My fault. You're right. I added an android:id to the images and then I used   ImageView test= (ImageView) tv.findViewById(R.id.idimage);

Comment: @Learningfrommasters - Glad it worked. That link was a nice find, by the way.